# Ping to an IP address received using connection sharing

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet, raspberry-pi

I am currently having a raspberry pi that has been set-up to receive an IP address using Internet Connection Sharing with a laptop running Ubuntu Quental. In this set-up, the Raspberry Pi is connected to the Ethernet port of the laptop using a cable.

The above laptop and other computers connect to the Internet using a Netgear Wireless router.

Using Internet Connection Sharing, the IP address that is assigned to the Raspberry Pi device is **10.42.0.91**.

All computers connecting to the internet using the Wireless router have their IP address as **10.3.3.x**

I now want to connect to the Raspberry Pi using a computer other than the laptop with which it shares the Internet connection. In other words, I simply want to access the Pi using my Mac or Windows laptops.

How should I go ahead with bridging the two Ip address?

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you're asking:

> How do I make the Raspberry Pi device accessible from any machine in the network ?

The simples solution would be to connect the Raspberry Pi device directly to your wireless router's LAN ethernet port so that it gets a `10.3.3.x` IP address. This way your Ubuntu laptop, and any other device connected to your network would have access to the `Pi`.

If for some reason you want the `Pi` to be connected only to your Ubuntu laptop but still make the device accessible to the network, you need to bridge your wired and wireless network interfaces on your laptop which also requires that your `wireless` card support `promiscuous mode`. You need to look for the steps to bridge `eth0` and `wl0`.